# javascript Uncaught ReferenceError: uneval is not defined

Tags: javascript

`Uncaught ReferenceError: uneval is not defined`

It works well with Firefox, but not work with Google Chrome.

I try:

```
var getSaved = [['ABC', 'http://...'], ['DEF', 'http://...'], ['...etc...']];
var get_saved_items = eval(getSaved);
var name = [], url = [];
for (var i = 0; i < get_saved_items.length; i++) {
    name[i].push(get_saved_items[i][0]);
    url[i].push(get_saved_items[i][1]);
};
window.localStorage.setItem('saved_name', uneval(name));
window.localStorage.setItem('saved_links', uneval(url));
```

it returns: `Uncaught ReferenceError: uneval is not defined`

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using 'eval' is not recommended because of different reasons (you can google it). `uneval` will not work in other browsers.

For your requirement you can use a JSON parser. Widely used one is Crockford's JSON parser.

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

```
var numbers = '[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]'; 
var names = '["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqr"]';

// string to Javascript object 
var numbersObject = JSON.parse(numbers);
var namesObject = JSON.parse(names);

console.log(numbersObject);
console.log(namesObject);

// Javascript object to string
numbers = JSON.stringify(numbersObject);
names = JSON.stringify(namesObject);

console.log(numbers);
console.log(names);
```

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/xVvBp/

Answer (score 1):

I believe `uneval` is just in SpiderMonkey, so just mozilla-based browsers.